# opentracing-go for high volume service

Tags: go, grpc, latency, opentracing

We recently implemented gPRC inject and extract spans for our inter-service communication module. And our service started showing latency. We have used code samples listed here - https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go I'm curious to know if this library has known issues with volume. There wasn't a case of missing spans. But, delay was noticed. Our volume was around 1M requests per second. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that particular library is responsible for your delays. I would inspect the tracer implementation library since it is responsible for storing your spans somewhere. Which tracer implementation library are you using?

Comment: Thanks Emin. That's zipkin-go. On local server it is shown to have a Mem usage of about 40 MB which isn't significant, As part of finding the root cause, I wanted to know if there are any issues with this kind of implementation.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I myself used jaeger-client-go implementation, which is compatible with zipkin. I remember having options to increase flush interval and buffer values for tracer and reporter so that the spans are not stored too often, assuming that impacts the performance of the service.